# Kendo Grid Angular - Columns Custom order of based on orderIdex

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a model where it contains field, title, and order index. I would like to load the columns based on the order index in the kendo grid (not in the sequence of the array). Data and fields are added dynamically.

fields:
[{field:"ProductName", Title: "Product Name", orderIndex: 0}, {field:"Amount", Title: "Amount", orderIndex: 1}]

Data:
[{ "ProductName":"Laptop-1", "Amount": 1000 }, { "ProductName":"Laptop-2", "Amount": 1500 }]

Using <kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of columns" [field]="column.field" [title]="column.title"> and (columnReorder)="columnReorder($event)"

I have tried the columnReorder event but not working as expected. Is there any way to show columns based on orderIdex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are generating them via `ngFor`, the elements will be created in the same order as the items are in the array.
In order for you to display the columns based on the `orderIndex` you need to sort the array itself. ([Example StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-63713005?file=app/app.component.ts))

Basically you have to do something like this:

```js
this.columns = fields.sort((a, b) => a.orderIndex - b.orderIndex);
```